# Selecting nearest polygon or point from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, coordinates, polygon

I have table full of polygons with their ids, names, coordinates and center points and types.
Its like:

```
> id             (int)
> name           (varchar)
> type           (set)
> polygon        (polygon)
> center_point   (point)
```

My polygons are like this
[image]

Every black have one red near to it... there is no other conncetion ... just every black have one red near to it.

I have every type='black' polygon's id and my question is how to select their nearest one of type='red'

---

EDIT:

Some sample data.
"Parent" is one of the black polygons and "Children #" are two of the red ones.
I need to find way to find out which one is closest... Maybe something with "center_point" ...

```
---- Parent polygon

polygon : [
                    25,20 ; 
                    60,20 ; 
                    60,45 ;
                    25,45 ; 
                    25,20 ;
                ]
center_point : [
                        45,45
                        ]






---- Children 1

polygon : [
                    10,320;
                    80,320;
                    80,370;
                    10,370;
                    10,320;
                ]
center_point : [
                        45,345
                        ]


---- Children 2

polygon : [
                    490,265;
                    570,265;
                    570,320;
                    490,320;
                    490,265;
                ]
center_point : [
                        530,290
                        ]
```

Comment: can you provide the sample dataset to analyse it

Comment: I will try - the info will be longitude and latitude of the polygon corners and lon,lat for the centroid's coordinates